# Merge two df by index for the object and its labelencoders

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames.

df1 has the columns `['City','State','Zip']`

df2 has the same columns but labelencoders of the same columns from df1. Here each of the index is the encoded label for each column.

I want to combine/merge these dataframes by the index.

How do I identify which label belongs to what and how do get them to one single dataframe, where the first three columns are going to be the original columns and its indexes `['City','State','Zip']`
and the next three columns are going to be their respected labels
`['City_encoded','State_Encoded','Zip_Encoded']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

By default, this will merge the two dataframes by index.